# Javascript/jQuery won't remove element in rails 3 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a system where in order to keep track of a projects progress, you can tag it with various versions (like the tagging feature on Stack Overflow. I am following along with Rails 3 book in action project, Ticketee.) I am trying to implement a asynchronous request to delete a tag from a ticket, but for some reason it's not deleting properly. Here is my code:

routes.html.erb

```
resources :tickets do
  resources :comments
  resources :tags do
    member do
      delete :remove
    end
  end
end
```

tags_controller.rb

```
def remove
@ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
if can?(:tag, @ticket.project) || current_user.admin?
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  @ticket.tags -= [@tag]
  @ticket.save
  render :nothing => true
end
end
```

views/tags/remove.js.erb

```
$('#tag-<%= @tag.name.parameterize %>').remove();
```

views/tags/_tag.html.erb

```
<span class='tag' id='tag-<%= tag.name.parameterize %>'>
<% if can?(:tag, @ticket.project) || current_user.admin? %>
<%= link_to "x", 
:remote => true, 
:url => remove_ticket_tag_path(@ticket, tag), 
:method => :delete, 
:html => { :id => "delete-#{tag.name.parameterize}" } %>
<% end %>
<%= tag.name %>
</span>
```

When I click the "x" link it refreshes the page, but doesn't actually remove it. Any idea why? I have posted the code that I think is relevant... let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have rails_ujs included ? rails_ujs is the one which does the cool stuff like link_to with remote. btw, its

> = link_to "x", url, :remote => true"

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#listing-all-posts

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to that syntax. How do I go about including rails_ujs?

Comment: I have //= require jquery_ujs in my javascripts/application.js file

Comment: The = link_to "x", url, :remote => true" syntax fixed it. Thank you very much